# MYSQL Client and server inside intel sgx

Tags: mysql, sgx

I have a MySQL Server which is inside SGX and serves the Clients which submits sql queries to the server to run the queries inside the intel SGX.
My question is that which protocol should be used for connection of these two machines (sql server(with sgx) and sql client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [TLS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) to create a secure channel between your server and your client. If data are transmitted in clear, then SGX becomes useless.

Comment: Thanks for you answer rather than TLS is there any other opportunities?

Comment: See MySQL's documentation. But why not use TLS, as it is the de-facto standard?